# How to connect > 1024 websockets with GlassFish 4

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish

I am using GlassFish 4 to host an application with websockets

My benchmarks indicate that only 1024 concurrent websockets can successfuly connect to GlassFish.

How can I increase the number of websocket connections that my application can support?

Comment: What are your websockets doing? If you are doing something like busy-waiting in the socket endpoint, then there is no way. Otherwise you'll need to give us a clue.

Comment: They're connecting and holding the connection open.  They're not constantly doing things.

Comment: Why would it make a difference if I were busy-waiting?

Comment: Because you would be tying up threads. Websockets are designed to do short running work with gaps in between. This way the limited number of cpus can deal with a large number of tasks. Usually webservers deal with request-response cycles. Websockets open the possibility of duplex communications which in turn open the possibility of abusing the webserver.

Comment: you can try increase max connections: go to admin console, then configurations > server-config > Network Config > Network Listeners > http-listener-1 -> Max Connections.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Websockets can do many long running tasks such as downloads and video streams (at least when it comes to the basic goals of it's design). Short/quick tasks would be ideal in most situations, but that's specifically not a part of the Websocket definition and is more a matter of server design (how are these tasks best handled/distributed once received via Websockets, etc)

Comment: @JSON it's a fact of _computer_ design that you cannot do two things at once on a single CPU. WebSockets are based around the concept of non-blocking IO which allows one CPU to deal with many taksks. If you tie up a CPU with a single, non-interruptible, task then no amount of "basic design goals" will help you. I'm not sure of the point you are trying to make - IO bound processes are inherently different to busy waiting, which is the example I used.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Yes, many tasks on one CPU, which should be strictly limited to IO and kept as simple as possible - all else goes to other threads/processors. It's we'll established that many thousands of active connections can be maintained by a non-blocking service using a single thread as long as the work is completed outside of this IO thread. Your completely right however if his box only has one processor available.